# I can not understand what numbers correspond to which areas in Kazakhstan

Tags: geolocation, geoip, maxmind

I downloaded the base GeoLite City, I can not understand what numbers correspond to which areas in Kazakhstan.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. However [this](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/misc/region_codes.csv) might be what you are looking for.